# Ajax-call on PrimeFaces 3.2 sometimes returns a crippled response

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

I am running a Web Application with, among other things, PrimeFaces 3.2 on a Wildfly 10.1.x server.
The entire application uses Spring WebFlow with loads of SubFlows and inherited components and whatnot.
The normal behavior (which we have most of the time) is, that an Ajax-Request is sent to the Flow, which triggers an action, and then returns a partial response which should be rendered.

Sometimes though, when I click on a button, the action is triggered, but the response is entirely crippled - a few tags are opened, but none are closed, and there is effectively no content.

Basically, something like this:

```
<partial-response>
  <changes>
    <update id="j_idt77">
      <![CDATA[
        <script type="text/javascript">
```

which of course leads to errors when trying to render it. Sometimes, refreshing the page resolves the issue, but most of the time, it does not.

I was unable to reliably reproduce this behavior, the next best thing I could do was cause a NullPointerException in the backing Java-Code, which in turn led to a broken flow, but the corresponsing response was entirely valid and not mutilated at all.

The Server Log hat no error messages whatsoever. As I got this as a bug report, and am so far unable to reproduce it, I cannot post any more details about the error, I have seen it, so I know it happens, but I have no idea how.

**EDIT**
Updated Error message.
Plus, a little more info here: 
the referenced id `j_jdt77` was used over several reloads, recached reloads and different browsers.
The id is not referenced anywhere in the currently rendered document, or the document to be rendered.
I don't know if that helps or not, but I certainly find it interesting and important enough to add.

**EDIT 2**

A bit more information that could be gathered by now:
The component `j_idt77` is a component, that should not be reloaded on a partial view. I can be sure of this as the partial re-rendering should only happen within a subform named `adminForm`, and on all successful calls, on every conceivable click-combination, all `<partial-response>` documents contained 3 - 4 ids for updating, one being `messages` for obvious reasons, the last being `javax.faces.ViewState` and the rest being id's of composure `adminForm:XXX` where XXX is the element to update.

`j_idt77` is a component that should be loaded once, so I am entirely unsure if that is relevant or not. I was able to trigger a reload of *a* component outside of that scope, however the ID's are differend now, because I added a `<ui:debug />` tag and changed the `PROJECT_STAGE` to `Development`. I am unsire how the id's are being generated right now, if my guess is correct (regular increment, basically the numbers are updated by a value of X with the extra settings) the element WOULD be a javascript resource.

Concerning updating: I was told that we could look into an update if it is  **guaranteed** to fix this behavior, so basically, I'd still need to know what exactly goes wrong here.

Comment: Checked all the issues that were fixed since 3.2? Hundreds...

Comment: Since an update of PrimeFaces 3.2 is, according to the employer, not an option, no, I did not check all fixed bugs in other versions. But thanks for your contribution =)

Comment: Then convince your employer that there are many additional advantages in 6.1 and up. So you'd better spend time on upgrading than on creating workarounds for an ancient version. And keep in mind that IF you find a fix in a newer version, you **know** what the issue was and that you can look at the source of the newer versions to create a backported patch

Comment: short inquiries tols that upgrading to 3.4 was attempted and would have created great difficulties on menus and such. So it seems that it is not too easy to do that. 
Sadly though, we have absolutely no indication if that will help at all, as we have no idea what the issue actually is. So, even if that was fixed, as long as we don't know what causes it, we don't know what to look for. I'm skimming the Forums right now, but so far, nothing

Comment: Some difficulties in upgrading have been 'reverted' in a newer version (so 4 or 5 could be easier). But I'm not aware of any real difficult menu issues. Datatable and filtering/sorting, yes.  Some related things: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/211. Checked if it is session-timeout related?

Comment: yes, timeout is not an issue. Since no exception is throws, I think I can also rule out "missing object in background", as well as interference from RichFaces

Comment: "a few tags are opened, but none are closed" which ones? Post an example of a broken response. Be careful with `<ui:debug />` - it may affect app's behavior, because it evaluates attributes on everything.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov the response posted in the original question is exactly what the server sends. nothing more. so the message contains `open partial response, open changes, open update, open script`

Comment: Mojarra's PartialViewContext & PartialResponseWriter can emit this kind of broken response if an exception happens during Render Response at certain times. Not sure why you don't see any error messages in the server log, but I suggest you keep looking for exceptions in your code. The exception may be happening when rendering something right after this `<script type="text/javascript">` line, but not necessarily if there is buffering.